# Is it possible to reload a gast principle machine gun in Flying Circus while flying?

Tags: weapons, flying-circus

I've been playing the RPG Flying Circus for a few weeks, and I really enjoy it. One problem, however, is the gun on my plane, which with the plane I chose is a fixed gast principle machine gun. It has five shots because all the ammo is fired very rapidly, which is useful for taking down targets but frustrating for long fights. Since the gun is fully accessible, could my pilot hypothetically carry a large chain of bullets around their torso and reload it when the initial stock of ammo runs out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Can you leave the pilot seat in mid-air to (do literally anything)?

Yes!

But!

> #### Empty Seat
>
> When **there is nobody flying the plane**, roll +Stability. On a 16+, the plane ploughs on for a while. On an 11-15, the plane starts listing, turning, or diving.
>
> If a PC is stuck in an aircraft with no pilot, like if they leave their seat to wingwalk [...] roll this to find out what happens. A partial hit is a good excuse to give Disadvantage while a character is wingwalking.

And perhaps also!

> #### Wingwalk
>
> When you **leave the safe areas of the plane**, whenever you are called to roll [a character] attribute, roll +Daring instead of what the move calls for.

(from "Support Moves", pp. 77-78 of hardcover *Flying Circus*)

So, extremely bad idea to do under any kind of combat pressure, not that it'll stop it from sometimes being a compelling idea. But even if you've just got clear skies to the next objective, not perfectly safe.

Reloading a gun is a simpler operation than putting out a fire or kickstarting an engine (things you would roll Patch Fix to do), so if you have got clear skies and the plane stays stable it's probably not a roll just to pull it off after that. Clear skies with partial stability and you're rolling regular +Daring to manage a full reload before the plane spins out; a failed stability roll on clear skies means disadvantage on the roll.